# In which part of the Gson codebase are circular references unhandled?

Tags: java, json

Is the exception generated during the conversion of JSON or during the writing of the JSON?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you answered your own question by constructing a test-case that produced a `StackOverflow` exception when JSON was not involved:   clearly, the `addChild` method is not programmed to recognize the *(obviously erroneous)* case when "the child that is to be added" is "the object itself." ("That," IMHO, "is a rather *serious* omission," but it's probably something that you can do nothing about.)

It is easy to foresee, then, that such an error could occur *either* when preparing the data, to be written as JSON, *or* when interpreting an incoming JSON stream.